# find and update a value of a dictionary in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I find the `dictionary` with value `user7` then update it's `match_sum` eg add 3 to the existing 4.

```
l = [{'user': 'user6', 'match_sum': 8}, 
        {'user': 'user7', 'match_sum': 4}, 
        {'user': 'user9', 'match_sum': 7}, 
        {'user': 'user8', 'match_sum': 2}
       ]
```

I have this, and am not sure if its the best practice to do it.

```
>>> for x in l:
...     if x['user']=='user7':
...         x['match_sum'] +=3
```

Comment: `list` is a  bad variable name. Apart from that, this code looks OK to me.

Comment: @karthikr thanks for pointing that out. I have renamed the list

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
l = [{'user': 'user6', 'match_sum': 8},
     {'user': 'user7', 'match_sum': 4},
     {'user': 'user9', 'match_sum': 7},
     {'user': 'user8', 'match_sum': 2}]

d = next(item for item in l if item['user'] == 'user7')
d['match_sum'] += 3
print(l)
```

prints:

```
[{'match_sum': 8, 'user': 'user6'},
 {'match_sum': 7, 'user': 'user7'},
 {'match_sum': 7, 'user': 'user9'},
 {'match_sum': 2, 'user': 'user8'}]
```

Note that if `default` (second argument) is not specified while calling `next()`, it would raise `StopIteration` exception:

```
>>> d = next(item for item in l if item['user'] == 'unknown user')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

And here's what would happen if `default` is specified:

```
>>> next((item for item in l if item['user'] == 'unknown user'), 'Nothing found')
'Nothing found'
```

Comment: Perfect!, I actually wanted to do something if no match is found. Helped a lot.

Answer (score -1):

If in case some one looking to directly update dictionay key's value present inside a list

```
l = [{'user': 'user6', 'match_sum': 8}, 
    {'user': 'user7', 'match_sum': 4}, 
    {'user': 'user9', 'match_sum': 7}, 
    {'user': 'user8', 'match_sum': 2}
    ] 
to_be_updated_data = {"match_sum":8}
item = next(filter(lambda x: x["user"]=='user7', l),None)
if item is not None:
    item.update(to_be_updated_data)
```

Output will be:

```
    [{'user': 'user6', 'match_sum': 8}, 
    {'user': 'user7', 'match_sum': 8}, 
    {'user': 'user9', 'match_sum': 7}, 
    {'user': 'user8', 'match_sum': 2}]
```